# Kivy RecycleView SelectableButton Does not switch to a Dynamic Layout Page

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Am working on a Project that has a RecycleView that contains details of patients.My aim is that when i click on a specific patient on the recycleView row, it should take me to specific dynamic page layout containing specific details of the selected patient in the RecycleView without using the Screen Manager, the switching of dynamic pages.how can i go about this?

i have created a method called change_dynamic_Layout() for switching dynamic pages and it works fine when using the normal button to call it. I have used a print statement in the method to show if the method is executed or not. But when i use the SelectableButton,the print statement is executed but the statement for changing page-layout is not. No errors is shown and  the dynamic page does not change. Here is the code try to run it and see what am talking about?

**Demo.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty, 
NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior



lost = Builder.load_file('Demo.kv')

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    #selectablebutton to call the change_dynamic_Layout() method in patient class    

    def on_enter(self):
        layout=Patient()
        layout.change_dynamic_Layout()



class victor(BoxLayout):
    pass
class Patient(Screen):
    manage_prescription: ObjectProperty(None)

    #Method to change the dynamic pagelayout

    def change_dynamic_Layout(self): 
        layout = Factory.victor()
        self.manage_prescription.clear_widgets()
        self.manage_prescription.add_widget(layout)
        print ('pressed')


class DemoApp(App):
    title = 'Hospital Management System'
    def build(self):
        n= Patient()
        return n 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DemoApp().run()
```

**demo.kv**

```
<Patient>:
    manage_prescription:manage_prescription

    BoxLayout:

        GridLayout :
            cols:1
            BoxLayout:
                id:manage_prescription
                orientation:'vertical'

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:40

                    Button:
                        text:"NO."
                        font_size: 25

                    Button:
                        text:"Date"
                        font_size: 25


                    Button:
                        text:"Patient"
                        font_size: 25


                    Button:
                        text:"Doctor"
                        font_size: 25
                        on_press: root.change_dynamic_Layout()


                BoxLayout:

                    RecycleView:
                        bar_width: 10
                        bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
                        bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
                        #effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
                        scroll_type: ['bars']
                        viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                        data:[{'text': str(x)} for x in range(20)]
                        SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                            cols:4
                            default_size: None, dp(56)
                            default_size_hint:1, None
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            multiselect: True
                            touch_multiselect: True





<victor>:
    Label:
        text:" Switched to specific page for patient's details"


<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    on_press: root.on_enter()
```

Any insight or help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `on_enter` method of the `SelectableButton` is creating a new `Patient` layout (`Screen`), and calling the `change_dynamic_Layout` method of that new `Patient` `Screen`. That newly created `Patient` `Screen` is not the one displayed in your app, so it has no effect on what you see. You actually want to call `change_dynamic_Layout` on the displayed `Patient` `Screen`. One way of doing this is to access it via `App.get_running_app().root`. So that your `on_enter` method can be changed to:

```
def on_enter(self):
    #layout=Patient()
    layout = App.get_running_app().root
    layout.change_dynamic_Layout()
```

Here is the entire python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recyclegridlayout import RecycleGridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior



lost = Builder.load_file('Demo.kv')

class SelectableRecycleGridLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleGridLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Button):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected

    #selectablebutton to call the change_dynamic_Layout() method in patient class

    def on_enter(self):
        #layout=Patient()
        layout = App.get_running_app().root
        layout.change_dynamic_Layout()



class victor(BoxLayout):
    pass
class Patient(Screen):
    manage_prescription: ObjectProperty(None)

    #Method to change the dynamic pagelayout

    def change_dynamic_Layout(self):
        layout = Factory.victor()
        self.manage_prescription.clear_widgets()
        self.manage_prescription.add_widget(layout)
        print ('pressed')


class DemoApp(App):
    title = 'Hospital Management System'
    def build(self):
        n= Patient()
        return n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DemoApp().run()
```

And here is the `Demo.kv`:

```
<Patient>:
    manage_prescription:manage_prescription

    BoxLayout:

        GridLayout :
            cols:1
            BoxLayout:
                id:manage_prescription
                orientation:'vertical'

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:40

                    Button:
                        text:"NO."
                        font_size: 25

                    Button:
                        text:"Date"
                        font_size: 25


                    Button:
                        text:"Patient"
                        font_size: 25


                    Button:
                        text:"Doctor"
                        font_size: 25
                        on_press: root.change_dynamic_Layout()


                BoxLayout:

                    RecycleView:
                        bar_width: 10
                        bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
                        bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
                        #effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
                        scroll_type: ['bars']
                        viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
                        data:[{'text': str(x)} for x in range(20)]
                        SelectableRecycleGridLayout:
                            cols:4
                            default_size: None, dp(56)
                            default_size_hint:1, None
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            multiselect: True
                            touch_multiselect: True





<victor>:
    Label:
        text:" Switched to specific page for patient's details"


<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    on_press: root.on_enter()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at least now something is happening but the patient screen widgets are not cleared at all, it only adds  the new page widget below the current page

Comment: Could you clarify? When I click on a `SelectableButton`, the screen is cleared completely and is replaced by a single `Label` that says "Switched to specific page for patient's details". Are you seeing something else?

Comment: yes, it is not clearing at all its adding below the current page. The Label that says Switched to specific page for patient's details" appearing below the recycle view in the current page

Comment: can you kindly post your code which has worked well so that i can confirm. i have  tried to decode mine, with no success

Comment: OK. thanks for entire  code, i have run it but still getting the same results. can't really figure what is the problem, because as you have said it is working properly in yours.

Comment: i think the clear_widget() statement is being skipped. I don't know why this is only happening to me. i have almost all the latest updates in kivy and python

Comment: using normal buttons, is works fine  but using selectable button, the clear_widget() and add_widget()  statement are being skipped